# Effective way to download zip using httpclient

Tags: c#

I am currently trying to build an application that automatically scrapes a webpage for updates and their respective download link and downloads if need be. Currently I am trying to figure the best way to download a ZIP file via HttpClient. The webpage I am accessing requires authentication so I am using httpclient to authenticate and create a cookiecontainer enabling me to download the required files, however, I've looked all through the API and cannot figure out how to download. I've tried various methods, however, none have yet to work. This is how the method looks like, but again I haven't been able to figure out a good way to download the zip

```
        var baseAddress = new Uri(url);
        var cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler() { CookieContainer = cookieContainer })
        using (var client = new HttpClient(handler) { BaseAddress = baseAddress })
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:33.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/33.0");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Connection", "keep-alive");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01");

            var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
            {
                 new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", username),
                 new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", password),
                      });

            //Download Files
            string[] download = getDownload().Split('/');
            foreach (string link in download)
            {
                string path = @".\" + link + ".zip";
                string dlink = url + link;
                var uri = new Uri(dlink);
```

Comment: You call the download link and save the stream to disk.

Comment: What I was asking for was more of an example. This is exactly what I've been trying, multiple different ways, and I have not been able to get any of them to work correctly.

Comment: You are adding some values to a `KeyValuePair<>` collection (which I really doubt is complete), but you are not posting them: `[HttpResponseMessage] response = await client.PostAsync([SomeURI], content))`. Then, if you have a positive (what is considered positive here you'll have to find out) response, you have to ask for a resource: `response = await client.GetAsync([Some Resource URI])`. If all is OK (= 200), you'll receive a stream transporting data you can save to disk (many ways of doing this).